# Can't import flup.server.fcgi

Tags: python, django, .htaccess, fastcgi, flup

I'm deploying a Django project following [this steps](http://simplyargh.blogspot.com/2012/04/python-27-django-14-on-bluehost.html)

my .htaccess is:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

my .fcgi:

```
#!/homeX/your_username/python27/bin/python27
import sys, os

# Add a custom Python path.
sys.path.insert(0, "/homeX/your_username/python27")
sys.path.insert(13, "/homeX/your_username/myproject")

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'
from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

When I run `python2.7 mysite.fcgi` to prove it is working, it throws me:

> Can't import flup.server.fcgi

How can I import `flup.server.fcgi`?

I'm using: `Django 1.8.7`, `flup 1.0.3`, `python 2.7`, `psycopg2` for `postgreSQL`, and all was download using `pip`.

Answer (score 8):

Which version of flup do you use ? It seems they released a new dev version on 10.12.2015 which is downloaded as the latest stable version and is python3 only. For me downgrading to `flup==1.0.3.dev-20110405` fixed the problem